# libreoffice xframe embed in swt

Tags: java, macos, swt, libreoffice

I'm a libreoffice java developer, i finsh the  below code on windows platform and it's work well.

```
            m_frame= xDoc.getCurrentController().getFrame();
            if(null==m_frame)
                return false;
            XWindow xWin= m_frame.getContainerWindow();
            XWindowPeer xWindowPeer = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XWindowPeer.class, xWin);
            XSystemDependentWindowPeer xSDWP=UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSystemDependentWindowPeer.class, xWin);

            byte[] procID = new byte[0];
            Object ptrWin=xSDWP.getWindowHandle(procID,SystemDependent.SYSTEM_WIN32);

            long lh=(long)ptrWin;

            if(null== m_compsiteXFrame)
                m_compsiteXFrame = new Composite(panelParent.getShell(), SWT.ALL);
            m_compsiteXFrame.handle=lh;
            m_compsiteXFrame.setParent(panelParent);
            m_compsiteXFrame.setBounds(panelParent.getClientArea());
```

I can see a libreoffice swriter window in my swt composite .
Then i move the code to macos and change swt lib jar from org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.3.jar to org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64-4.3.jar
and changed some code :

```
           Object ptrMac=xSDWP.getWindowHandle(procID,SystemDependent.SYSTEM_MAC);

            long lh=(long)ptrMac;

            if(null== m_compsiteXFrame)
                m_compsiteXFrame = new Composite(panelParent.getShell(), SWT.ALL);
            m_compsiteXFrame.view.id=lh;
            m_compsiteXFrame.setParent(panelParent);
```

Then i always get a crash. i google many times but have not seen any code or doc  can work.
Please help me , let me know the correct code how to work.

The stack trace:

```
Current thread (0x00007f9c1a009000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=259, stack(0x00007ff7b5aea000,0x00007ff7b62ea000)]

Stack: [0x00007ff7b5aea000,0x00007ff7b62ea000],  sp=0x00007ff7b62e6648,  free space=8177k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x6057]  objc_msgSend+0x17
J 325  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x000000011722d609 [0x000000011722d540+0x00000000000000c9]
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView.subviews()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSArray;+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite._getChildren()[Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control;+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.invalidateChildrenVisibleRegion()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.invalidateVisibleRegion()V+49
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.releaseParent()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setParent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+45
j  emrpad.init(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+182
j  Application.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a9cb9]  _ZN9JavaCalls11call_helperEP9JavaValueRK12methodHandleP17JavaCallArgumentsP6Thread+0x1fd
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3f1841]  _ZL17jni_invoke_staticP7JNIEnv_P9JavaValueP8_jobject11JNICallTypeP10_jmethodIDP18JNI_ArgumentPusherP6Thread+0x10a
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3f507f]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x1d5
C  [libjli.dylib+0x5e22]  JavaMain+0xa9e
C  [libjli.dylib+0x8222]  __JVMInit_block_invoke+0x4b
C  [Foundation+0x414a2]  __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+0x7
C  [Foundation+0x4139a]  -[NSBlockOperation main]+0x62
C  [Foundation+0x41331]  __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__+0x11
C  [Foundation+0x4059f]  -[NSOperation start]+0x311
C  [Foundation+0x80b03]  __NSThreadPerformPerform+0xb3
C  [CoreFoundation+0x808fd]  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+0x11
C  [CoreFoundation+0x80865]  __CFRunLoopDoSource0+0xb4
C  [CoreFoundation+0x805e4]  __CFRunLoopDoSources0+0xf2
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7f01b]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x37d
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7e5dd]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x233
C  [libjli.dylib+0x78a4]  CreateExecutionEnvironment+0x17d
C  [libjli.dylib+0x3cab]  JLI_Launch+0x507
C  [java+0xf64]  main+0x174
C  0x000000010f69a4fe

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 325  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(JJ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x000000011722d594 [0x000000011722d540+0x0000000000000054]
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView.subviews()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSArray;+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite._getChildren()[Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control;+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.invalidateChildrenVisibleRegion()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.invalidateVisibleRegion()V+49
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.releaseParent()V+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setParent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+45
j  emrpad.init(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+182
j  Application.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
```

Whenever call any api i always get a crash , even just call a simple api view.bounds() , i am sure the lh is a 64bit long value not null or zero that return from getWindowHandle():

```
Object objMac=xSDWP.getWindowHandle(procID,SystemDependent.SYSTEM_MAC);
long lh=(long)objMac;
m_compsiteXFrame = new Composite(panelParent.getShell(), SWT.NONE);
m_compsiteXFrame.view.id=lh;
m_compsiteXFrame.view.bounds();
```

the stack traces:

```
Current thread (0x00007f850200e800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=259, stack(0x00007ff7b01d8000,0x00007ff7b09d8000)]

Stack: [0x00007ff7b01d8000,0x00007ff7b09d8000],  sp=0x00007ff7b09d4838,  free space=8178k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x6817]  objc_msgSend_stret+0x17
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend_stret(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;JJ)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView.bounds()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;+16
j  emrpad.init(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+184
j  Application.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3a9cb9]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle const&, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1fd
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3f1841]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x10a
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3f507f]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x1d5
C  [libjli.dylib+0x5e22]  JavaMain+0xa9e
C  [libjli.dylib+0x8222]  __JVMInit_block_invoke+0x4b
C  [Foundation+0x414a2]  __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__+0x7
C  [Foundation+0x4139a]  -[NSBlockOperation main]+0x62
C  [Foundation+0x41331]  __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__+0x11
C  [Foundation+0x4059f]  -[NSOperation start]+0x311
C  [Foundation+0x80b03]  __NSThreadPerformPerform+0xb3
C  [CoreFoundation+0x808fd]  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+0x11
C  [CoreFoundation+0x80865]  __CFRunLoopDoSource0+0xb4
C  [CoreFoundation+0x805e4]  __CFRunLoopDoSources0+0xf2
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7f01b]  __CFRunLoopRun+0x37d
C  [CoreFoundation+0x7e5dd]  CFRunLoopRunSpecific+0x233
C  [libjli.dylib+0x78a4]  CreateExecutionEnvironment+0x17d
C  [libjli.dylib+0x3cab]  JLI_Launch+0x507
C  [java+0xf64]  main+0x174
C  0x000000011323a4fe

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend_stret(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;JJ)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView.bounds()Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;+16
j  emrpad.init(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+184
j  Application.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00007fa89c1ab6e0

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007ff7b09d48a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f850200e800
RBX={method} {0x00000001100e4640} 'objc_msgSend_stret' '(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;JJ)V' in 'org/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/OS'
RCX=0x0000000116f1c680 is at code_begin+0 in 
[CodeBlob (0x0000000116f1c610)]
Framesize: 0
BufferBlob (0x0000000116f1c610) used for jni_fast_GetDoubleField
RDX=0x00007ff831e2f52e: <offset 0x1a98752e> in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib at 0x00007ff8174a8000
RSP=0x00007ff7b09d4838 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f850200e800
RBP=0x00007ff7b09d48e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f850200e800
RSI=0x00007fa89c1ab6e0 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00007ff7b09d4850 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f850200e800
R8 =0x00007ff831e2f52e: <offset 0x1a98752e> in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib at 0x00007ff8174a8000
R9 =0x000000061f79dbb0 is an oop: org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSRect 
{0x000000061f79dbb0} - klass: 'org/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect'
R10=0x00007ffffffffff8 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000110cb9628: _ZN20SafepointSynchronize18_safepoint_counterE+0 in /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib at 0x000000011035b000
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13={method} {0x00000001100e4640} 'objc_msgSend_stret' '(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/NSRect;JJ)V' in 'org/eclipse/swt/internal/cocoa/OS'
R14=0x00007ff7b09d49a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f850200e800
R15=0x00007f850200e800 is a thread
```

Comment: For anyone else reading this, note that it is about "Mac OS" and not about LibreOffice "Macros" as I thought at first.

Comment: As far as a response to the question, I don't have a Mac so I cannot test the code. But perhaps it's a bug, either with LibreOffice on a Mac or possibly Java (that `swt-macos.jar` you mentioned). It might be worth filing a report on the LibreOffice bug tracker to see if anyone there can help.

Comment: What crash do you get? Can you [edit] your question and include the stack trace? Any chance for a [mcve]?

Comment: `SWT.ALL` is not a valid style for a `Composite`. There is not enough information here to help, what error do you get? Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks all guys , i had fix this problem  ,by JNI set the nsview's parent to the java swt widget.